# obtener y enlazar href por id en php

Tags: php, sql

Hola Buenas Uso este código para obtener los resultados de la base de datos SQL

```
<?php
require_once('db/conexion.php');
require('inc/header_por.php'); 


    $search_keyword = '';
    
 
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM db_revistas WHERE titulo LIKE :keyword order by id DESC';
    
    /* Pagination Code starts */
    $per_page_html = '';
    $page = 1;
    $start=0;
    if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
        $page = $_POST["page"];
        $start=($page-1) * NRO_REGISTROS;
    }
    $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . NRO_REGISTROS;
    $pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
    $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pagination_statement->execute();

    $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
    if(!empty($row_count)){
        $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
        $page_count=ceil($row_count/NRO_REGISTROS);
        if($page_count>1) {
            for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                if($i==$page){
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="links_pagcurrent" />';
                } else {
                    $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="links_pag" />';
                }
            }
        }
        $per_page_html .= "</div>";
    }
    
    $query = $sql.$limit;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $resultados = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
?>

<ul id="filter">
   <?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
</ul>

    <div class="center">                
                    
<form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>

<?php
    if(!empty($resultados)) {
        foreach($resultados as $row) {
    ?>
            <div class="span-6 inner-6 tt view">
        <div class="item" style="text-align:center">
            <a href="/revista/<?php echo $row['enlace'];?>" class="spec-border-ie" title="<?php echo $row['titulo'];?>">
                <img style="display:none" alt='<?php echo $row['titulo'];?>' title='<?php echo $row['titulo'];?>' style="width:130px;height:190px;background-color: #717171;"><?php echo $row['portada'];?></img>
            </a>
        </div>

  <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Bien todo este código funciona perfectamente hace búsqueda, paginación y muestra los resultados de la base de datos, pero lo que no hace es ir al post_id ya que no esta creado, me explico, esto es como si fuera la portada de una web y quiero añadirle la opción de leer más y que valla al enlace y muestre los resultados de los detalles o sea la continuación de "leer mas"

y no se como implementarlo pero quiero añadirle que al hacer click en un resultado vaya al post_id no se si me explico.

Gracias y Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre es lo siguiente:

1. crear un archivo llamado post_completo.php
2. crear el enlace "leer mas" en el código que estas compartiendo, me imagino que dentro del div, algo así:

```php
<a href="post_completo.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_post'];?>">LEER MAS</a>
```

Si pasas por arriba del enlace el mouse en la barra de status abajo de todo, te tiene que decir algo asi: post_completo.php?id=1 (o el id que tenga)

En este punto ya estaríamos obteniendo el id que viene via URL al archivo post_completo.php

podemos comprobarlo de la siguiente manera...

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Si el ID que te esta llegando es correcto, listo, solo hace falta lo siguiente

3. volver hacer una consulta sql y te muestre el contenido de ese post siempre y cuando el ID sea igual al ID que esta en la base de datos. osea:

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM db_revistas WHERE id_post='.$_GET['id];

id_post es el ID de los post que estan en tu base de datos (capas q se llame id solo o id_post, es cuestión de fijarse)
$_GET['id] es el ID que viene via URL

4. Listo, solo hace falta recorrer el $sql como lo hiciste en tu archivo principal y mostrar por pantalla el resultado, obviamente que vas a tener que sacar la paginacion y demas validaciones

Comment: perfecto amigo ya lo he hecho funcionar te lo agradezco de corazón...

a ver si me puedes ayudar con esta otra duda que entre comillas esta ligada a este proyecto posteada [aqui]
(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374542/funcion-enc-y-dec-en-javascript-no-consigo-que-funcionen)

Yo es que soy autodidacta y aun me queda mucho por aprender cosa que hago cada día