# funcion enc() y dec() en javascript no consigo que funcionen

Tags: javascript

### ¿Porque no funciona?

Muy buenas Tengo dos funciones en JavaScript para codificar texto pero no logro hacerlas funcionar,la verdad es que ya la hice funcionar hace unos meses pero aparque el proyecto y ahora al retomarlo no logro recordar como lo hice.

```
<script>
 
 function enc (data) {
    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        enc = "",
        tmp_arr = [];
 
    if (!data) {
        return data;
    }
 
 
    do { // pack three octets into four hexets
        o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
        o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
 
        bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;
 
        h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
        h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
        h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
        h4 = bits & 0x3f;
 
        // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
        tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
    } while (i < data.length);
 
    enc = tmp_arr.join('');
    
    var r = data.length % 3;
    
    return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}

function dec (data) {




    var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
        ac = 0,
        dec = ""
        tmp_arr = [];
 
    if (!data) {
        return data;
    }
 
    data += '';
 
    do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
        h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
        h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
 
        bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
 
        o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
        o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
        o3 = bits & 0xff;
 
        if (h3 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
        } else if (h4 == 64) {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
        } else {
            tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
        }
    } while (i < data.length);
    dec = tmp_arr.join('');
    document.getElementById('decod').value= dec;
 
    return dec;
}
</script>


<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="input" id="codificar" placeholder="escribir aquí..."></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="CODIFICAR" onclick="enc()">





    <textarea name="input" id="decod" placeholder="Aquí resultado..."></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="DECODIFICAR" onclick="dec()">

</form>
```

esto se supone que está codificado con esta función y trato de decodificarlo, este es un fragmento de lo que codifique hace unos meses antes de aplazar este proyecto. Muy difícil no puede ser ya que yo que no tengo muchos conocimientos de JavaScript.

```
agwxeHMxSTFAQ0NAQkZHMTsxAQMAB3hzdAMxSTFAMTsxcgBzdDFJMXV1AHZACEYARkdBeDE7MXtwfXYxSTFUYl8xOzECBnB7eAUKMUkxA3dz
```

Saludos

Comment: Consejo, siempre siempre hay que documentar el código y evitar así después dolores de cabeza, por cierto edité tu pregunta pues indicas código JS y usas la Tag de PHP

Comment: tienes toda la razón hay que comentar el código  es verdad la etiqueta lo siento

Comment: @Jflabur me imagino que es un proyecto personal de superacion o algo asi, ya que supongo estas conciente de las funciones `atob` y `btoa` las cuales permiten codificar y decodificar en base64, que es el formato que aparentemente deseas usar para codificar y decodificar. la verdad es que si no es un proyecto de superacion o no es por hacer un ejercicio de programacion es mucho mas facil y rapido usar atob y btoa, pues estas son funciones integradas en javascript que tienen ese proposito, pero me parece interesante esta pregunta, voy a probar a decodificar para ver si es correcto.

Comment: Efectivamente tu codificacion es incorrecta, pero la verdad no he jugado mucho con el formato base64 como para recrearlo, hare unas pruebas para ver si puedo recrear un codificador y decodificador de base64 ya que estamos.

Comment: De hecho tienes un caracter extra que no es original de base64 en tu codificacion, tecnicamente no estas usando base64, estas usando en teoria base65 que nisiquiera se si existe xd

Comment: exacto amigo es un codificador que programo mi hermano mayor que desgraciadamente ya no esta entre nosotros desde este invierno por un accidente de moto, y para mi tiene valor sentimental, rebuscando entre los archivos he encontrado lo que parece ser un decodificador te lo paso a ver si así logras hacer que decodifique y codifique.

gracias

Comment: te pongo el enlace ya que tiene mucho caracteres para pegarlo como texto
es un archivo .js
http://jflabur.epizy.com/enc.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en la forma en que pretendes usar tus 2 funciones. Además tienes un error de tipeo en una de ellas, te falta una coma en la función `dec()` cuando declaras variables:

```
var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
    ac = 0,
    dec = "" // <- aquí te falta una coma
    tmp_arr = [];
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para solucionar el problema debes emplear manejadores de eventos. Sin alterar casi nada el código de tus funciones, ya que hacen los que se les pide. Ambas devuelven una cadena codificada / decodificada o devuelven `undefined`.

Tal vez sería mejor si cambias los nombres de variables por algo más intuitivo.

Para usar manejadores de eventos debes crear una función que se ejecute al hacer clic en los botones adecuados, y las mismas se encargarán de llamar a tus funciones `enc()` y `dec()` modificando los elementos `textarea` correspondientes. Por ejemplo:

```js
function enc (data) {
  var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
  ac = 0,
  enc = "",
  tmp_arr = [];
 
  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }

  do { // pack three octets into four hexets
    o1 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o2 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    o3 = data.charCodeAt(i++);
    bits = o1 << 16 | o2 << 8 | o3;
    h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
    h2 = bits >> 12 & 0x3f;
    h3 = bits >> 6 & 0x3f;
    h4 = bits & 0x3f;
    // use hexets to index into b64, and append result to encoded string
    tmp_arr[ac++] = b64.charAt(h1) + b64.charAt(h2) + b64.charAt(h3) + b64.charAt(h4);
   } while (i < data.length);

  enc = tmp_arr.join('');
  var r = data.length % 3;
  return (r ? enc.slice(0, r - 3) : enc) + '==='.slice(r || 3);
}

function dec (data) {
  var b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var o1, o2, o3, h1, h2, h3, h4, bits, i = 0,
      ac = 0,
      dec = "",
      tmp_arr = [];
  if (!data) {
    return data;
  }
 
  data += '';
 
  do { // unpack four hexets into three octets using index points in b64
    h1 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h2 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h3 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    h4 = b64.indexOf(data.charAt(i++));
    bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;
    o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
    o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
    o3 = bits & 0xff;
    if (h3 == 64) {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1);
    } else if (h4 == 64) {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2);
    } else {
      tmp_arr[ac++] = String.fromCharCode(o1, o2, o3);
    }
  } while (i < data.length);

  dec = tmp_arr.join('');
  return dec;
}

// manejadores de evento clic

const onClickEnc = event => {
  //manejador para boton codificar
  document.getElementById('decod').value = enc(document.getElementById('codificar').value);
}

const onClickDec = event => {
  //manejador para boton decodificar
  document.getElementById('codificar').value = dec(document.getElementById('decod').value);
}

// añadimos los manejadores de evento a los eventos clic de ambos botones

document.getElementById('encButton').addEventListener('click', onClickEnc);

document.getElementById('decButton').addEventListener('click', onClickDec);
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="input" id="codificar" placeholder="escribir aquí..."></textarea>
  <input id="encButton" type="button" value="CODIFICAR">
  <hr>
  <textarea name="input" id="decod" placeholder="Aquí resultado..."></textarea>
  <input id="decButton" type="button" value="DECODIFICAR">
</form>
```

Ahora que ya tienes un código funcional, podemos decodificar la cadena que dices tener codificada:

> `agwxeHMxSTFAQ0NAQkZHMTsxAQMAB3hzdAMxSTFAMTsxcgBzdDFJMXV1AHZACEYARkdBeDE7MXtwfXYxSTFUYl8xOzECBnB7eAUKMUkxA3dz`

El resultado sería:

> `j1xs1I1@CC@BFG1;1xst1I1@1;1rst1I1uuv@FFGAx1;1{p}v1I1Tb_1;1p{x 1I1ws`

Al parecer tu cadena no está realmente codificada usando tu función de codificación.

Comment: gracias amigo como resultado me da lo mismo que en https://www.base64decode.net/ te agradezco el esfuerzo por la ayuda

saludos